# Calculate DateTime difference between data of two files

Tags: awk, sed

I have  two files File1 & File2 and File1 have data like

```
"Start Date & Time" = 1804030000
```

and File2 have data like

```
"End Date & Time" = 1804030400
```

Both file have same amount of lines that is almost 300K lines. Now i want to calculate time difference by subtracting (End date & Time(File2) - StartDate & Time(File1)) and store the result in new file line by line.

Datetime format in both files like (yymmddhhmm).

Comment: The format "*yymmddhhmmss*" requires 12 chars of data.  The data given is only 10 chars.

Comment: yes caz the module which writing this log file is omitting seconds portion that is ss

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A small executable: `busybox` is able to parse date formats with the -D option.
The format from the files date is `%y%m%d%H%M`

```
$ busybox date -uD %y%m%d%H%M -d "1804040400"
Wed Apr  4 04:00:00 UTC 2018
```

Using that in awk:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{  a="busybox date -uD %y%m%d%H%M +%s -d " }
         { b=a $6  ; b | getline sd ; close(b)
           b=a $NF ; b | getline ed ; close(b)
           print(ed,sd,ed-sd)
         }' < <(paste infile[12])

1522814400 1522713600 100800
```

Note: Using the `-u` option will avoid some DST and local effects. Most of the time it does not change the final difference as both date commands are executed with the same environment TZ.

Answer (score 0):

I would use `awk` and first converted the `Start Date & Time` and `End Date & Time` to a valid *date* that `date` command can understand in this format `yymmdd HH:mm` then convert each to [*epoch*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time) time to calculate the difference in *seconds*.

```
$ awk '{endDateInEpoch="date -d""\""substr($NF,1,6)" "substr($NF,7,2)":"substr($NF,9,2)"\""" +%s";
        endDateInEpoch |getline endDateInEpoch;close(endDateInEpoch); 

        startDateInEpoch="date -d""\""substr($6,1,6)" "substr($6,7,2)":"substr($6,9,2)"\""" +%s";
        startDateInEpoch |getline startDateInEpoch;close(startDateInEpoch);

        sec=endDateInEpoch-startDateInEpoch; sec*=(sec)?1:-1; print sec" seconds"
}' <(paste file[12])
100800 seconds
```

Note that first I do `paste file[12]` to paste both *files1* and *file2* side by side which will result like below, then pass that to `awk` input where `$NF` points to the last field `1804040400` as *End Date & Time* and field#6 `1804030000` as *Start Date & Time* with whitespaces as field delimiters which is `awk`'s default `FS` **F**ield **S**eperator:

```
"Start Date & Time" = 1804030000        "End Date & Time" = 1804040400
```

Comment: please consider to accepting the answer if it's resolved your question by clikcing the ✔️next to the answer. also read [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers)